# In Objective-C is there a way to get a list of the methods called by a method?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have been doing some research online and have found that using the `ObjectiveC` package in Objective C you can get a list of all the methods on a class using `class_copyMethodList()`, and I see you can get the implementation (`IMP`) of a method using `instanceMethodForSelector:`. The Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SEL) has been helpful so far but I'm stuck and not sure what I'm really looking to find.

**I want a list of the methods/functions called in a given method's implementation** so I can build a call tree.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The runtime can't give you this information; the runtime only knows the location (address) of a method's code block start and metadata about that method. If you want to build a call tree from existing binary code, you'd need to scan the instruction stream. There may be a way of getting something like this from the compiler statically, though-- I don't know-- or certainly working backwards from instrumented code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is kind of hard way, and will cause a line of code in every method You can also make use of sqlite and save the tracked methods..

> MethodTracker.h

```
@interface MethodTracker : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *methodTrackArr;

+ (MethodTracker *)sharedVariables;

@end
```

> MethodTracker.m

```
@implementation MethodTracker

static id _instance = nil;

+ (MethodTracker *)sharedVariables
{
    if (!_instance)
        _instance = [[super  allocWithZone:nil] init];

    return _instance;
}

// optional
- (void)addMethod:(NSString *)stringedMethod
{
    // or maybe filter by: -containObject to avoid reoccurance
    [self.methodTrackArr addObject:stringedMethod];
    NSLog("current called methods: %@", methodTrackArr);
}

@end
```

and using it like:

> OtherClass.m

```
- (void)voidDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[MethodTracker sharedVariables] addMethod:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FUNCTION__]];
    // or directly
    [[MethodTracker sharedVariables].methodTrackArr addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FUNCTION__]];
}
- (void)someOtherMethod
{
    // and you need to add this in every method you have (-_-).. 
    [[MethodTracker sharedVariables] addMethod:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FUNCTION__]];
}
```

i suggest you import that `MethodTracker.h` inside `[ProjectName]-Prefix.pch` file.

**Sorry**, for the double answer, i deleted the other one and i have no idea how did that happen..

> ***Hope this have helped you or at least gave you an idea.. Happy coding,
>   Cheers!***

Answer (score 0):

I think in the runtime track `method` is possible, but `function` not.

I have been build a tool [DaiMethodTracing](https://github.com/DaidoujiChen/DaiMethodTracing) for trace all methods activity in single class for some of my need. This is based on objective-c method swizzling. So, there is an idea to do this

1. List all Classes in your application.
2. swizze all the methods in each class.
3. filter the method you want to trace.

finally, you may got the `method` call path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I would rather not have to do this from within the project though. I would really rather have an independent tool that I could run on an existing project without having to make modifications to it.